# Passing and displaying data in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, segue

I'm quite new to swift but i've been trying to pass json data from one view controller into a UITableView, However im struggling to actually display any data in the tableview cell

ViewController
(sends data to second view controller)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let index = indexPath?.row
let movieDetails = filteredMovies[index!]
let movieDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! MovieDetailsViewController

movieDetailsViewController.posterUrl = movieDetails.value(forKeyPath: "backdrop_path") as? String
movieDetailsViewController.coverUrl = movieDetails.value(forKeyPath: "poster_path") as? String
movieDetailsViewController.movieTitle = movieDetails.value(forKeyPath: "title") as? String
movieDetailsViewController.movieRating = movieDetails.value(forKeyPath: "vote_average") as! NSNumber as NSNumber

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let movieReleaseDateString = movieDetails.value(forKeyPath: "release_date") as? String
let movieReleaseDate = dateFormatter.date(from:movieReleaseDateString!)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy"
movieDetailsViewController.movieReleaseDate = dateFormatter.string(from: movieReleaseDate!)

    movieDetailsViewController.movieOverview = movieDetails.value(forKeyPath: "overview") as? String
}
```

MovieDetailsViewController

```
  var newMovies: [NSDictionary] = []
    var movieTitle: String!
    var movieRating: NSNumber!
    var movieReleaseDate: String!
    var movieOverview: String!
    var posterUrl: String!
    var coverUrl: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 800
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.newMovies.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailCell") as!
    DetailTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel!.text = movieTitle
    cell.overviewLabel!.text = movieOverview

    cell.releaseLabel.text = movieReleaseDate
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
   numberFormatter.numberStyle = .none
   let movieRatingString = numberFormatter.string(from: movieRating)
    return cell
}
```

DetailTableViewCell

```
 @IBOutlet weak var coverView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var posterView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var overviewLabel: UILabel!
```

I have setup the storyboard so that a TableViewCell cell has a title, releasedate and overview labels aswell as a UIImage. My intention is that the user selects a movie from the table view from viewController (which works so far) and is then segued to MovieDetailsViewController where more details are displayed

Printing to console has also confirmed that data has been sent to the second view controller
I assumed that:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailCell") as!
    DetailTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel!.text = movieTitle
```

would be sufficient in order to print the data in the table view cell ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is how you are using `newMovies` in `MovieDetailsViewController`. I don't see anywhere in the code where `newMovies` is being populated with data. If such is the case, your count will always be zero and not populate the table view cell.

Comment: And so, would it be possible to append movieTitle etc to an empty array of newMovies ? assuming that would solve it?

Comment: To answer your question, if you append `movieTitle` or any other properties to `newMovies` then yes, it would work.